# Dynamically Use jQuery Options in Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

Not sure if I'm approaching this correctly ...

Basically I have a plugin structure along the lines of:

```
(function($){

$.fn.xxxxx = function(options) {

    var o = {
        widgets: 'a,b,c',
        a: {
            id: 'abc',
            title: 'ABC'
        },
        b: {
            id: 'def',
            title: 'DEF'
        },
        c: {
            id: 'ghi',
            title: 'GHI'
        }
    };

    var options = $.extend(o, options);

    return this.each(function(options){

        var myplugin = {
            init: function(){
                var x = o.widgets.split(',');
                $.each(x, function(i,v){
                    myplugin.widgets(i,v);
                });
            },
            widgets: function(i,v){

                var t = o.v.title ? '<h3>'+o.v.title+'</h3>' : '' ;

            }
        }
        myplugin.init();
    });
};
```

})(jQuery);

Is it possible to use the string values from the o.widgets option to then call one of the o.a, o.b, o.c options?

Basically the a, b or c would be passed to the widgets function and then used to assign the option value. The following is what I want it to do but it obviously doesnt work like that:

```
var t = o.v.title ? '<h3>'+o.v.title+'</h3>' : '' ;
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one of the nice things about Javascript in particular is that the following are equivalent:

```
foo.bar === foo['bar'];
```

So if you want to access `o.a`, you can access it via `o['a']`.
Taking that further, you can fashion a function like the following:

```
function herp (opt) {
    return o[opt];
}
```

... and call it like `var foo = herp('a');` or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var t = o['a'].title ? '<h3>' + o['a'].title + '</h3>' : '';
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
var v = 'a';
var t = o[v].title ? '<h3>' + o[v].title + '</h3>' : '';
```